# Negative values in time measurement?

Tags: c, linux, time

I'm trying to measure time in milliseconds:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    struct timespec start, end;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
            usleep(500000); // Sleep 500 milliseconds
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);

            printf("Elapsed time: %lf \n", (((end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) / 1.0e3) + ((end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1.0e6)));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the `printf` function I subtract the seconds and divide by 1000 to convert the result into milliseconds, then I subtract the nano seconds and divide with 1000000 to convert the result into milliseconds, and finally the two results are added.

I think this is the correct way, but for some reason the output contains negative values:

```
Elapsed time: 500.117421 
Elapsed time: -499.882167 
Elapsed time: 500.193631 
Elapsed time: -499.884990 
Elapsed time: 500.115007 
Elapsed time: -499.877328 
Elapsed time: 500.127219 
Elapsed time: -499.875301 
Elapsed time: 500.124021 
Elapsed time: -499.865300
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure with this: `... / 1.0e3)`. This should be `... * 1.0e3)`, shouldn't it?

Comment: The problem is in your unit conversion. You need to multiply by 1e3 to convert seconds to nanoseconds.  Once you are adding two differences with the same units, the result should be positive.

Comment: @DavidRoundy: "*..to nanoseconds*" you want to say "*... to milliseconds*", won't you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert seconds to Milli-seconds you need multiply the seconds by 1000.

So this

```
printf("Elapsed time: %lf \n",
  (((end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) / 1.0e3) + ((end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1.0e6)));
```

should be

```
printf("Elapsed time: %lf \n", 
  (((end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1.0e3) + ((end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1.0e6)));
```

Comment: Argh, I don't know why I failed to see this. Thank you.

Comment: @user4793972: Sxxt happens. This however won't happen to you again ... ;-)